# Page Template Custom Options

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have a little question. I am making a wordpress template that uses custom page templates. Now i ran into a problem. I want to create a page with a intro text and blog posts that come from a certain category. When a user creates a new page, I want them to be able to select the category from witch the posts are shown. Kinda like a drop down box with category's from where they can select the category they want. Does anyone maby knows a tutorial where I could learn how to do this ?

I mean something like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/10/naamloosea.jpg/

I already searched google but I could only find tutorials on how to make a template options page.

Thanks in advance,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

You would want to create a Meta Box to save the category as a custom field entry within Pages. In here you could list the categories within a select box. You could then use this in the page template to pull in the posts from that category as you wish. I'll see if I can dig out a decent tutorial for this.

I did a quick search and found the following plugin for WordPress that may be of use... http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/map-categories-to-pages/